# Is it possible to have something performed automatically when receiving an email? (google apps free)

Tags: email, web, google-apps-script, gmail

Say for example if I receive an email to subscribe@mydomain.com, is there a way I can trigger that to make a GET or POST call to my own server?

Another use could be email a link and have my server download the link automatically if the email meets certain criteria.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script is perfect to achieve this. You need to use GmailApp, Script Triggers etc from Google Script to automate it.

Best Regards

[Apps Script Tutorials](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/)

Comment: To expand a little, you'd set up a filter to label incoming messages, like "New". And create another filter, "Processed".

Comment: Accidentally hit enter. To continue, In Google Apps Script, you would write the script and set it to run every 5-10 minutes. It would get all the messages with the "New" label `GmailApp.getMessagesForThread("New");` You'd process the messages and replace the "New" label with "Processed". If you don't do that, it will attempt to handle every message, every time it runs. Or you could simply delete the message after you process it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, a service like [ifttt](http://ifttt.com) might solve your problem without you having to write ay code.